# Find Median of Two Sorted Arrays in JS

Tags: javascript, algorithm, programming-challenge, ecmascript-6, median

**The task**
is taken from [leetcode](https://leetcode.com/problems/median-of-two-sorted-arrays/)

> There are two sorted arrays nums1 and nums2 of size m and n
>   respectively.
>
> Find the median of the two sorted arrays. The overall run time
>   complexity should be O(log (m+n)).
>
> You may assume nums1 and nums2 cannot be both empty.
>
> **Example 1:**
>
> nums1 = [1, 3]
>
> nums2 = [2]
>
> The median is 2.0
>
> **Example 2:**
>
> nums1 = [1, 2]
>
> nums2 = [3, 4]
>
> The median is (2 + 3)/2 = 2.5

**My solution**

```
/**
 * @param {number[]} nums1
 * @param {number[]} nums2
 * @return {number}
 */
var findMedianSortedArrays = function(nums1, nums2) {
  let i1 = i2 = 0;
  let smallest, valBefore;
  const pivot = Math.floor((nums1.length + nums2.length) / 2);

  while (nums1[i1] || nums2[i2]) {
    smallest = (nums2[i2] === void 0 || nums1[i1] < nums2[i2])
      ? nums1[i1++]
      : nums2[i2++];

    if ((nums1.length + nums2.length) % 2) {
      if (pivot === i1 + i2 - 1) {
        return smallest;
      }
    } else {
      if (pivot - 1 === i1 + i2 - 1) {
        valBefore = smallest
      }
      if (pivot === i1 + i2 - 1) {
        return (smallest + valBefore) / 2;
      } 
    }
  }
};
```

This is the first idea that I had and it reached 99th percentile. I guess you can't take this evaluation seriously. And I'm sure there's a better solution.

Comment: By the way, you have a bug: if the arrays are both `[-1,0,1,2,3,4,5]`, then `nums1[1]||nums2[1]` will be false, and the loop will exit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The 99th percentile is due to the linear nature of your approach. The goal of this exercise is to figure out a logarithmic one.

I don't want to spell out the algorithm entirely. Just a hint to get you started. Take a middle element of `nums1`. Find its lower bound in `nums2`; call it `i2`. In the sorted array the selected element would be at the position `nums1.length/2 + i2`. I hope the hint is a good enough.

---

`pivot` doesn't look like a good name to me. `totalLength`, perhaps?

---

The complicated logic inside the loop also hurts the performance. Consider looping until you reach the midpoint:

```
    while (i1 + i2 < pivot)
```

and do the final median finding afterwards.